# Android - Quick way to bulk install private app on to 100+ devices?

Tags: android

What are the options for quickly installing my private Android app on to over 100 devices?

I know I can create a private listing on Google Play but, if I go that route, how to get it on all my devices?

Another requiremnt is that I would also like to make **updating** the app on all devices as quick/painless as possible, too.

**Update**

All the devices are fresh out of the box, so they won't have email (or Google accounts) set up on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, we uploaded the apk to the server and programmed an NFC tag with the URL. Then just tapped each device on the NFC tag to start the install process...

Answer (score 0):

We have some ways to delivery without Google Play

- Send to emails (on these devices) with attachment apk
- Use https://rink.hockeyapp.net to distribute build then share the publish link to devices
- Share a link (your apk), android device can download and install

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think registering all the devices on hockeyapp could be too time consuming. But you've got me thinking that putting a link to the apk on an NFC card and tapping the devices onto that may be the quickest way(?)

Comment: @ban-geoengineering: don't need to register the email on the hockey server. You distribute build then setting in the publish. You can share the url for these email.